# Bounds on solutions of elliptic pde's in the whole plane

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, potential-theory

My question is rather simple. Given $f$ a $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ function with zero mean but supported in the whole plane, is there a bound of the form 
$$
\|\nabla(\Delta)^{-1} f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\leq C\|f\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}?.
$$
Any comment or reference is very welcome!

Comment: may be using Fourier Transform...

Comment: Consider $f_r(x)=f(rx)$ then $\| f_r\|_{L^2}=r^{-n/2}\| f\|_{L^2}$ and $\| \nabla (\Delta^{-1})f_r\|_{L^2}=r^{-n/2-1}\| \nabla(\Delta^{-1})f\|_{L^2}$.

Comment: But how can you bound the singularity of the multiplier at zero? Using the zero mean you have 
$$
\frac{i \xi}{|\xi|^2}\left(\hat{f}(\xi)-\hat{f}(0)\right)= \int_0^1\nabla_\xi\hat{f}(\lambda\xi)d\lambda
$$

Comment: Is $f$ compactly supported?

Comment: @ShuhaoCao No, it is not.

Comment: @Jose27 How do you get $\|\nabla(\Delta)^{-1} f_r\|$?

Comment: @Rafa: $\Delta^{-1} f=u$ is the solution of $\Delta u=f$ so that $u_r=r^{-2}u(rx)=\Delta^{-1}f_r$. Take the gradient and change variables.

Comment: So... the answer is no :-(. Thank you @Jose27